# iphone/objective-c: using singleton class as a container for globals

Tags: iphone, objective-c, singleton, global-variables

So I'm finding that I'm using a singleton User class to access global variables throughout an iphone app.  In some cases I use the instance in almost all the methods within a class. So in the first few lines of each method I have statement such as:

```
User *user = [User sharedManager];
```

This is obviously not a very DRY implementation.  My question is:  instead of repeating this statement in all the methods I need to access User can't I just instantiate this once, say in the initializer, and then set a property equal to this pointer such as:

```
-(id)init {
.....
self.sharedUser = [User sharedManager];
....
}
```

and then reference this property in each method instead of instantiating the singleton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure, you can do this. There might be (small) issues with code readability, but there's nothing wrong with this.

Comment: Cool, thanks thats what I thought.  ALso I think the readability issues would be dwarfed by the non-DRYness of the other approach

Comment: I cannot see the benefit of it. `[[User sharedManager] doSomething]` is probably just as fast as `[self.sharedUser doSomething]`.

Comment: @Georg.  I'm more concerned about setting or getting the globals:  self.sharedUser.sharedValue = someValue;  is certainly more concise and efficient than [User  sharedManager].sharedValue =  someValue;

Answer (score 1):

Why not just introduce a global that points to your singleton instead.  Whilst its "less pure", you are trading off end-user performance.  self.sharedUser.sharedValue will have exactly the same run-time cost as [[User sharedManager] sharedValue]

Dot notation for properties is about the stupidest thing that was ever added to Objective-C - it confuses the crap out of people who think its someway more efficient.

Now, if you meant self->sharedUser->sharedValue then you would be avoiding the property-method lookup and using two pointer-deferences instead - thats going to be about as fast as having globalUser->sharedValue, but has the added overhead of needing a new pointer in every instance of every class that wants to access the globals.